# How to scrape info from table with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the following kind of HTML table's columns, I can't get the numeric values under the quotation marks with the find_all('td')[i].text command. Python returns me blank values instead of 3.03, 1.21, etc...
Please can someone help me catching those values?

```
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="5lmp0xv464x0xf55p3"><span><span><span data-odd="3.03"></span></span></span></td>
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="5lmp3xv464x0xf55p9"><span><span><span data-odd="1.21"></span></span></span></td>
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="3.23" data-oid="5lmovxv464x0xf55p1"></td>
```

```
find_all('td')[i].text ---> Output : blank vaues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.text` won't work cause, the expected values are no texts. Select all the elements by its attribute (`data-odd`) and extract the value:

```
for e in soup.select('[data-odd]'):
    print(e.get('data-odd'))

-> 3.03
   1.21
   3.23
```

or only from `<span>`

```
for e in soup.select('span[data-odd]'):
    print(e.get('data-odd'))

-> 3.03
   1.21
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="5lmp0xv464x0xf55p3"><span><span><span data-odd="3.03"></span></span></span></td>
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="5lmp3xv464x0xf55p9"><span><span><span data-odd="1.21"></span></span></span></td>
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="3.23" data-oid="5lmovxv464x0xf55p1"></td>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('[data-odd]'):
    print(e.get('data-odd'))
```